# Java Spark SQL: Merging and overwriting Datasets with identical schema

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Java 11 and Spark SQL 2.13:3.3.2 here. Please note: I'm using and interested in the Java API and would appreciate Java answers, but I can *probably* decipher Scala-based answers and do the necessary Scala-to-Java conversions if necessary. But Java would be appreciated!

---

I have 2 `Dataset<Row>` instances, both with the same exact schema (same columns/headers, which are the same types):

```
data set #1 (ds1)
===
fruit,quantity
--------------
apple,50
pear,12
orange,0
kiwi,104

data set #2 (ds2)
===
id,fruit,quantity
--------------
banana,50
pineapple,25
orange,5
blueberry,15
```

I would like to "*merge*" these 2 `Dataset<Row>`s so that they are appended or joined to one another, but in such a way that `ds2` overwrites any values in `ds1` if their `fruit` columns match. So `orange` is in both data sets, but in `ds2` its quantity is `5`, so that should be the final listing in the resultant `Dataset<Row>` output. So in other words, this operation should results in a 3rd data set like so:

```
data set #2 (ds2)
===
id,fruit,quantity
--------------
apple,50
pear,12
orange,5
kiwi,104
banana,50
pineapple,25
blueberry,15
```

The order of the rows does not matter, all that matters to me is that the list of fruits in both data sets are listed in the 3rd, and that `ds1` rows are **updated** (not inserted) if there is a matching fruit in `ds2`.

I took a look at `Dataset#join` JavaDocs, but they seem to be just useful for when you need the SQL equivalent of an `inner join`, but won't help me with the desired overwrite functionality.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: What if in ds2 you have 2 orange with different quantity values, or that will never happen ?

Comment: Great point @AbdennacerLachiheb but in my use case that won't happen. In each DS the fruits will be unique.

Comment: OK I see, I posted an answer for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "full" join to get all values from both dataset, then use coalesce to get the preferred column values:

```
ds2 = ds2.withColumnRenamed("fruit", "fruit2").withColumnRenamed("quantity", "quantity2");
ds1.join(ds2, ds1.col("fruit").equalTo(ds2.col("fruit2")), "full")
        .withColumn("fruit", functions.coalesce(col("fruit"), col("fruit2")))
        .withColumn("quantity", functions.coalesce(col("quantity2"), col("quantity")))
        .drop("fruit2", "quantity2")
        .show();
```

Result:

```
+---------+--------+
|    fruit|quantity|
+---------+--------+
|     kiwi|     104|
|   orange|       5|
|    apple|      50|
|     pear|      12|
|   banana|      50|
|pineapple|      25|
|blueberry|      15|
+---------+--------+
```